# border radius partially broken

Tags: css

I tried the `overflow:hidden` solution for a background which breaks `border-radius`: http://jsfiddle.net/ypjDC/17/

```html
<div style="width: 200px; border: 3px solid; border-radius: 7px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="float: left; width: 50px; background-color: #800000;">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>

  <div style="float: right; width: 50px; background-color: #800000;">test</div>

  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

but there is always a problem, you can see a little white space on the corners.

How can I correct that?

Comment: White space? Not exactly sure what you are referring to...there might be some anti-aliasing / sub-pixel issues but nothing that is really apparent to the naked eye.

Comment: Yup, you cannot really do anything about that. Or you should divide it in 3 parts: 1 left part with a background, border-top/left/bottom, border radius topleft, bottomleft -- 1 mid part with a border-top/bottom -- 1 right part with a background and a border-top/right/bottom, border radius righttop, border radius rightbottom.

Comment: As @Paulie_D has stated, I too don't see anything wrong. Is it on any specific browser?

Comment: @davey i tried your solution like this : http://jsfiddle.net/AzJUD/3/ but my box-shadow is broken :( because the box-shadow is not on a div with the border ?

Comment: @Harry : i use chromium last version

Answer (score 2):

You can add a inset box-shadow that has the same color of your border to your main DIV :

```
<div style="width: 200px; border: 3px solid; border-radius: 7px; overflow: hidden;box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #000 inset;">
```

It modify a bit your border appearance, but remove the white area.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcgMp/)**

Comment: Made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcgMp/1/) to help see the difference between what you did and after.